# behave HOOK Error empty dict from behave.ini

Tags: python, python-behave

I'm getting error **HOOK-ERROR in before_all: KeyError: 'environment'** when running behave from command line

Project Structure:

```
features/ * all feature files go here
features/steps * all steps go here
features/environment.py
```

behave.ini (at the project level)

```
 [behave.userdata]
 environment = int
```

environment.py

```
def before_all(context):
   userdata = context.config.userdata
   print(userdata)
   print(userdata['environment'])
```

output

```
{}
HOOK-ERROR in before_all: KeyError: 'environment'
```

On a site note, if i run the features files using pycharm, I dont get this error and the environment printed out. Behave v1.2.6

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried moving `behave.ini` to the `features/` directory and I'm able to access `userdata['environment']` when I run Behave from the `features/` directory.

Comment: Thank you, it does work when you move the behave.ini into the features folder. As per the documentation the file can reside in the current working directory, which i assumed it to be the root directory which has the features directory

Comment: I'm glad it helps. Does that answer your question/help to resolve your issue? If so, please mark this as the Selected Answer!

Answer (score 0):

This should resolve your issue:

```
x = context.config.userdata.get('environment')
```